# Distance between a 3D point and a vector defined by two 3D points

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

[Drawing of the vector and line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wKx5.png)

I have vector points A (Xa, Ya, Za) and B (Xb, Yb, Zb)

Point to measure the distance from;
C (Xc, Yc, Zc)

I don't know if it's correct, but this is my equation for distance: D = (|(C-A) * (C-B)|) / (|B-A|)

Can I split that formula to:

Dx =    (|(Xc-Xa) * (Xc-Xb)|) / (|Xb-Xa|)

Dy =    (|(Yc-Ya ) * (Yc-Yb)|) / (|Yb-Ya|)

Dz =    (|(Zc-Za) * (Zc-Zb)|) / (|Zb-Za|)

, to get the X distance, Y distance and Z distance from the point to vector?

If that equation is even correct.

I'm pretty insecure since I'm still in high school and don't know much about 3D math. Would really appreciate if you helped me out or gave me a better solution if there is one. (This is for game programming purposes)

Comment: Does `*` refer to the cross product here? If so, it's still not quite correct. You want the distance from C to the line going through AB?

Comment: Are you looking for the distance to the line through $A$ and $B$ or to the line _segement_ $\overline{AB}$? If the latter, then you also have to deal with the case that the perpendicular from $C$ doesn’t intersect the segment at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\theta$ be the angle between the vectors $\overrightarrow{AC}$ and $\overrightarrow{AB}$. Then, the distance, i.e. the length of the perpendicular drawn from $C$ to $AB$ is

$$d = \vert\overrightarrow{AC}\vert\sin\theta$$

You also know the cross product

$$ \vert\overrightarrow{AC} \times \overrightarrow{AB}\vert = \vert\overrightarrow{AC}\vert\vert\overrightarrow{AB}\vert\sin\theta $$

therefore

$$ d = \frac{\vert \overrightarrow{AC} \times \vec{AB} \vert}{\vert\vec{AB}\vert} $$

---

**EDIT:** To find the perpendicular vector, consider the projection vector of $\overrightarrow{AC}$ on the line $AB$. Let's call this $\overrightarrow{D}$. Then its length is given by

$$ \vert\overrightarrow{AD}\vert = \vert\overrightarrow{AC}\vert\cos\theta = \frac{\overrightarrow{AC}\cdot \overrightarrow{AB}}{\vert \overrightarrow{AB} \vert} $$

where the dot product identity was used. Since $\overrightarrow{AD}$ is in the same direction as $\overrightarrow{AB}$, you can find its coordinates by "scaling" $\overrightarrow{AB}$, i.e.

$$ \overrightarrow{AD} = \vert \overrightarrow{AD} \vert \frac{\overrightarrow{AB}}{\vert\overrightarrow{AB}\vert} = \frac{\overrightarrow{AC}\cdot \overrightarrow{AB}}{\vert \overrightarrow{AB} \vert^2} \overrightarrow{AB}$$

The perpendicular vector, $\overrightarrow{DC}$, is computed by the difference

$$ \overrightarrow{DC} = \overrightarrow{AC} - \overrightarrow{AD} $$

The 3 components of $\overrightarrow{DC}$ are the $x$, $y$, $z$ distances you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much!


Just to be sure, for x distance, I can take x values of the points, for y distance, I take y and for z distance, I take z values of points?

Comment: @MarinKovač It doesn't work like that. You need all 3 coordinates to compute the cross product. The result is just the total distance. What you're asking is finding the perpendicular *vector* from C to AB, which is entirely different.

Comment: I added some more information on the perpendicular vector. Hopefully you know how to compute the cross and dot products.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. :D